# How to produce executable with rustc?

Tags: rust

If I compile this simple program `fn main() { println!("Hello"); }` with `rustc test.rs -o test` then I can run it with `./test`, but double clicking it in the file manager gives this error: `Could not display "test". There is no application installed for "shared library" file.` Running `file test` seems to agree: `test: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object...`.

How can I get rustc, and also tools that use it such as cargo, to produce executables rather than shared objects?

I am using 64-bit Linux (Ubuntu 14.10).

EDIT: I have [posted](http://discuss.rust-lang.org/t/why-does-rust-produce-shared-libs-rather-than-executables-on-linux/998) on the [Rust forum](http://discuss.rust-lang.org) about this.

EDIT@: So it turns out this is an issue with the `file` executable.

Comment: It isn't a shared library, it is a position-independent executable. They're similar, but not quite the same. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables

Answer (score 2):

What you have described is not entirely consistent with what I observe:

```
$ rustc - -o test <<< 'fn main() { println!("Hello"); }' 
$ ./test
Hello
$ file test
test: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=99e97fcdc41eb2d36c950b8b6794816b05cf854c, not stripped
```

Unless you tell rustc to produce a library with e.g. `#![crate_type = "lib"]` or `--crate-type lib`, it will produce an executable.

It sounds like your file manager may be being too smart for its own good. It should just be trusting the executable bit and executing it.

Comment: that looks the same as what the OP got from `file test`, I think the problem might be the gui file manager not recognizing it. but when i compile oter languages, i get "LSB executable" rather than shared object too...

Comment: `file` is telling you that is a shared library, not an executable. You are having the same issue I have.

Comment: @mm865: whether it is reporting it as one or the other, *it is executable* and can be executed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the rust compiler and can't find its docs on the internet, but I know how to do shared obkect vs executable in C, so maybe this info will help you out in solving it.

The difference is the -pie option to the linker. With a hello world C program:

```
$ gcc test.c -ohello -fPIC -pie
$ file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

If we remove the position-independent flags, we get an executable:

```
$ gcc test.c -ohello
$ file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

Both generated files work the same way from the command line, but I suspect the difference `file` sees is changing what your GUI does. (Again, I'm not on Ubuntu... I use Slackware without a gui file manager, so I can't confirm myself, but I hope my guesses will help you finish solving the problem yourself.)

So, what I'd try next if I was on your computer would be to check the rustc man page or `rustc --help` and see if there's an option to turn off that `-pie` option to the linker. It stands for "position independent executable", so look for those words in the help file too.

If it isn't mentioned, try `rustc -v test.rs -o test` - or whatever the verbose flag is in the help file. That should print out the command it uses to link at the end. It'll probably be a call to `gcc` or `ld`. You can use that to link it yourself (there's probably a flag `-c` or something that you can pass to `rustc` to tell it to compile only, do not link, which will leave just the `.o` file it generates).

Once you have that, just copy/paste the final link command `rustc` called and remove the `-pie` option yourself.... if it is there... and see what happens.

Manually copy/pasting isn't fun to do and won't work with tools, but if you can get it to work at least once, you can confirm my hunch and maybe ask a differently worded question to get more rust users' attention.

You might also be able to tell the file manager how to open the shared object files and just use them. If the manager treated them the same as programs `file` identifies as executables, as the command line does, everything should work without changing the build process. I don't know how to do that though, but maybe asking on the ubuntu stack exchange will find someone who does.

Comment: The `rustc` flag to disable `-pie` is apparently `-C dynamic-no-pic` but the correct fix seems to be changing the file manager or the file identification thing to understand these are executables.

Comment: In case somebody else stumbles onto this: The flag is now `-C relocation-model=dynamic-no-pic`. However passing that flag is not enough when compiling on a platform whose C compiler has `--enable-default-pie` enabled ([relevant `rustc` issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35061)). So if you compiled with the above flag and still see *LSB shared object* with `file` you need to pass `-C relocation-model=dynamic-no-pic -C link-args=-no-pie` instead.